# Include tikz pictures in main script

Tags: tikz-pgf, include, standalone

I include all my tikz figures with `\includestandalone{filename}`.

I am using `\tikzset` after `\begin{document}` in all my `tikz` figure files but I use `\usetikzlibrary` in the header (outside of `\begin{document}`), making it necessary to also tell which `tikz` libraries to use in the main script.

How can I avoid writing `\usetikzlibrary` in both the `tikz` figure files AND the main script?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are your TikZ files can be compiled stand alone? or just code, which can be compiled only in main document? In later case both files should have the same libraries and TikZ settings. In this case you can this settings store in separate packate, for example mytikzsetings and load them in main document and in files with TikZ pictures

Comment: They can compile stand alone. I just hoped I could just include the libraries inside the stand alone files rather than both in the stand alone files and the main script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us say you have this standalone file named `plotting.tex`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
]
\addplot[blue] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which compiles stand alone and produces a graph.

Now let us say this is your main file

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includestandalone[mode=buildnew]{plotting}
  \caption{interesting results}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here we used `subpreambles=true` in  `\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}` so that sub preambles are written to a `.sta` file in the first run and in the second run, included in the main file. So compiling two times should get you on track. You may be also interested in `sort` and `print` options. More on these can be found in `standalone` documentation, section 5.2, page 21.

[image]